# Save both input video and output video in Open CV python

Tags: python, opencv

i write a code from Open CV Document about Motion Detection .i want to save my input as a video and my output as a video but i have problems. i save video but i can just save the output video and some time the input video is the same out put video.my input video is from my computer's camera and it's like a normal video but the output is that video in addition by squares around motion objects.i need your help.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
(grabbed, frame) = cap.read()
fshape = frame.shape
fheight = fshape[0]
fwidth = fshape[1]
print (fwidth , fheight)


ret, frame1 = cap.read()
ret, frame2 = cap.read()

while cap.isOpened():
    diff = cv.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(diff, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    _, thresh = cv.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

    dilated = cv.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(dilated, cv.RETR_TREE, 
    cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

   for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(contour)

    if cv.contourArea(contour) < 100:
        continue
    cv.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
    Final_Movie = cv.putText(frame1, "Status: {}".format('Movement'), (10, 
    20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,
               1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
#cv.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

 cv.imshow("feed", frame1)
 cv.imshow("feed1", blur)
 cv.imshow("feed2", gray)
 cv.imshow("feed3", diff)
 cv.imshow("feed4", thresh)
 cv.imshow("feed5", dilated)
 #cv.imshow("feed6", contours)



 frame1 = frame2
 ret, frame2 = cap.read()
 if cv.waitKey(40) == 27:
     break

 cv.destroyAllWindows()
 cap.release()
```

i tried this but it doesn't work.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
(grabbed, frame) = cap.read()
fshape = frame.shape
fheight = fshape[0]
fwidth = fshape[1]
print (fwidth , fheight)

fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (fwidth, fheight))
out1 = cv.VideoWriter('input.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (fwidth, fheight))

ret, frame1 = cap.read()
ret, frame2 = cap.read()

while cap.isOpened():
    diff = cv.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(diff, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    _, thresh = cv.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

    dilated = cv.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(dilated, cv.RETR_TREE, 
    cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

   for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(contour)

    if cv.contourArea(contour) < 100:
        continue
    cv.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
    Final_Movie = cv.putText(frame1, "Status: {}".format('Movement'), (10, 
    20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,
               1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
#cv.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

 cv.imshow("feed", frame1)
 cv.imshow("feed1", blur)
 cv.imshow("feed2", gray)
 cv.imshow("feed3", diff)
 cv.imshow("feed4", thresh)
 cv.imshow("feed5", dilated)
 #cv.imshow("feed6", contours)

 if ret == True:
    out.write(Final_Movie)
    out.write(frame2)

 frame1 = frame2
 ret, frame2 = cap.read()
 if cv.waitKey(40) == 27:
     break

 cv.destroyAllWindows()
 cap.release()
```

Comment: you have wrong indentations

Comment: what size has frame from `.avi` ? 640, 480 ? if it has different size then you have to change size before you save it in `cv.VideoWriter(..., (640, 480))`. It will not save frame if it has wrong size.